# How to pass JSON input to JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am trying to figure out a way to produce test execution charts from cucumber produced JSON.

I looked into `JFreeChart` and would like to know if there a way to use JSON as input for `JFreeChart` or  other java library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`JFreeChart`](http://www.jfree.org) won't read your JSON format data out-of-the-box, so you'll need to write your own code to process the JSON file/string and populate a dataset accordingly.  I did something like this recently for [Orson Charts](http://www.object-refinery.com/orsoncharts/), and used [`json-simple`](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) to do the JSON parsing.  Of course, the code I wrote parses only a very specific set of JSON formats. I don't know the details of the "cucumber produced json" that you need to process, but hopefully the `json-simple` project can help you to get it done.